# Initialization in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form error

Tags: c, openmp

I'm getting `Initialization in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form` error in the first for loop in the parallel section the line under the `unsigned int seed = omp_get_thread_num();`. I've tried removing the  `int i =0` in the `for` loop and changing it to a `i =0` and declaring `private(i)` same error. Any ideas?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cfloat>
#include <omp.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10



double threadsafe_rand(unsigned int* seed, double min, double max)
{
    double range = (max - min);
    double div = RAND_MAX / range;
    return min + (rand_r(seed) / div);
}

int main() {
    int i;
    double a[ARRAY_SIZE], b[ARRAY_SIZE], c[ARRAY_SIZE], d[ARRAY_SIZE], e[ARRAY_SIZE], f[ARRAY_SIZE], y[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int imin, imax;

    /*A[10] consists of random number in between 1 and 100
    B[10] consists of random number in between 10 and 50
    C[10] consists of random number in between 1 and 10
    D[10] consists of random number in between 1 and 50
    E[10] consists of random number in between 1 and 5
    F[10] consists of random number in between 10 and 80*/



    srand(time(NULL));



    double min = DBL_MAX;
    double max = -DBL_MAX;

#pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(a,b,c,d,e,f,y,imin,imax,min,max) private(i)
    {
        unsigned int seed = omp_get_thread_num();

#pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            a[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 100);
            b[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 10, 50);
            c[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 10);
            d[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 50);
            e[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 5);
            f[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 10, 80);
            y[i] = (a[i] * b[i]) + c[i] + (d[i] * e[i]) + (f[i] / 2);

        }

            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
                a[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 100);
                b[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 10, 50);
                c[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 10);
                d[i] = threadsafe_rand(&seed, 1, 50);

                if (y[i] > max) {
#pragma omp critical
                    if (y[i] > max) {
                        max = y[i];
                        imax = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // printout 
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            printf("Y[%d]=%.2f\n", i, y[i]);
        }
        printf("min y[%d] = %.2f\nmax y[%d] = %.2f\n", imin, min, imax, max);

    }
```

Comment: You declare `i` private, but then you redeclare it in the loop header. Remove the outer `i`. Always keep your variables as local as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by remove the "outer i" do you mean remove the `private(i)` ?

Comment: No the `int i` declaration before the loop. You should always keep declarations as local as possible.